# Fake Async With Observable Subscription: 1 Timer Still in the Queue

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, jasmine, observable

I'm writing unit tests for my component that retrieves a status through an Observable chain and display it in a status badge in the UI. The implementation works great but I'm running into issues verifying the data using `jasmine` and `fakeAsync`

**Component.ts**:

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class EmployerQuickactionsComponent {
  private activeTag: Tag = { severity: 'success', text: 'Active'};
  private inactiveTag: Tag = { severity: 'danger', text: 'Inactive'};
  private selectedClinic$: Observable<Clinic> = this.modelService.selectedClinic$;

  selectedEmployer$: Observable<Employer> = this.modelService.selectedEmployer$;

  employerTag$: Observable<Tag> = combineLatest([this.selectedEmployer$, this.selectedClinic$]).pipe(
    debounceTime(250),
    mergeMap(([employer, clinic]) => {
      if (!employer.id || !clinic.id) {
        return of(null);
      }

      return this.clinicSiteEmployerService.get(employer.id, clinic.id).pipe(
        map(clinicSiteEmployer => clinicSiteEmployer.isActive ? this.activeTag : this.inactiveTag)
      );
    })
  );

  constructor (<dependencies>) { }
}
```

The *debounceTime* operator bypasses a race condition which I could re-architect. But this has me curious if there's a way to use `fakeAsync` and subscribe to an Observable in the same test.

Here is my **Component.spec.ts**:

```
describe('EmployerQuickactionsComponent - Inactive Employer', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
   ...
  });

  it('should be initiated', fakeAsync(() => {
    tick(250);
    expect(fixture.componentInstance).toBeTruthy();
  }));

  it('should display tag if clinic selected', fakeAsync(() => {
    tick(250);
    expect(screen.getByLabelText('employer-action-tag')).toBeTruthy();
  }));

  it('should set inactive tag if employer is inactive', fakeAsync(done => {
    tick(250);
    fixture.componentInstance.employerTag$.subscribe((tag) => {
      expect(tag.severity).toBe('danger');
      expect(tag.text).toBe('Inactive');
      done(); // throws error
    });
  }));
```

The spies all return the appropriate mock data. The error I'm getting is `1 timer(s) still left in the queue.`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This issue arises due to Observable waiting in the fakeAsyn zone, to avoid this issue you can use flush() to avoid such situation.
Example -
ts -

```
     export class NetworkService {
      constructor(private toastsService: ToastsService) {}
    
      public async refreshData(): Promise<void> {
        await Promise.resolve(); // fake network call
        this.toastsService.addToast("Data refreshed.");
      }
    }
```

Spec.ts -

```
      it("should add a toast", fakeAsync(() => {
      const toastsService = TestBed.inject(ToastsService);
      const toasts = toastsService.getToasts();
    
      service.refreshData();
    
      flushMicrotasks();
    
      // the following assertions will pass
      expect(toasts.length).toBe(1);
      expect(toasts[0].message).toBe("Data refreshed.");
    
      // without flush at the end, the test will fail with
      // Error: 1 timer(s) still in the queue.
      flush();
    }));
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/test/fake_async_spec.ts#L273

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Ashray can you give more information (links, examples, etc.)?

Comment: @NathanFoss  Please check the updated answer and let me know if you have any concerns.